# XYZ Tiles missing in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis, xyz-tiles

I just updated QGIS to version 3.2. And noticed that the XYZ Tiles is missing. Are they removing it from QGIS 3, because I couldn't find any information about it? Does anyone know where I can find it or do I have to go back to QGIS 2 to get XYZ Tiles? Here is the screenshot for the current map source screen in QGIS 3.2.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it doesn't appear in the "Add Layer" dialog, I can add XYZ tiles from this option in the "Browser" panel:

[image]

Right-click to add a new tile server connection, or choose one of the existing ones.

If you don't have a "Browser" panel open, use View... Panels... Browser to get one.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion that you can get the XYZ Tiles from the "Browser" Panel is misleading since there is no panel named Browser in QGIS 3.
The only way to get this option is to open the "Add Layer" window and select the 'Browser' tab from there.

[image: QGIS 3.4]
*Where the browse button is in the QGIS 3.4 Data Source Manager*

Comment: I have in 3.14 (and have had in earlier 3x versions) a panel named Browser which I can turn off and on using the typical right button click on the toolbar.  I leave it on.  XYZ tiles are there as always.

Comment: Browser Panel exists in QGIS 3.x (see the screenshot in my answer an this site): if it is not visible, you can re-activate it: Menu view > Panels > Browser

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering that this fantastic script by Klas Karlsson has not yet been linked here:
https://twitter.com/klaskarlsson/status/972757121933733889?lang=de

Open your python console in QGIS (Ctrl-Alt-P or from the plugins menu), copy/paste the code from here and run:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py

[image]

This adds about three dozens XYZ tiles basemaps.

There are also basemaps than can be accessed by plugin, e.g. [OpenLayers plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/openlayers_plugin/) and [QuickMapServices plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/).